# Squid authentication helpers

Tags: ssl, squid, ntlm

I set up squid with  authentication helper following along the line the guide here
http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/authentication_with_squid
the only difference is that my users together with NTLM password hashes are stored in a mysql database.

The php-function that compute the ntlm hash is the following.

```
function ntlm_hash($txt)
{
        $txt = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16LE', $txt);
        $md4 = bin2hex(mhash(MHASH_MD4, $txt));

        return strtoupper($md4);
}
```

Now I am bit concerned about security and I do not want to use basic http authentication. I know one solution is to use SSL with squid, but by default squid on debian  is built without SSL support.
The other solution I was thinking is to use NTLM authentication helper; the protocol is described here
http://squid.sourceforge.net/ntlm/squid_helper_protocol.html

Unfortunately I did not find anything interesting to guide me (besides the specification at the link), does anybody know how a possibile implementation may works? For instance it is not clear if I can implement the protocol only with NTLM password hashes. Does anybody have other suggestions to strengthen the user authentication? Considering that I have only available the NTLM hash of the password.